# UIProgressView how to make it circular

Tags: ios, customization, uiprogressview

I'm moving the first passes with iOS programming. I want to make a progress bar circular, can someone tell me how to make it?

Comment: Here are some circular progress bar. https://www.cocoacontrols.com/tags/circular

Comment: For my own progress meters I used a custom NSView and over-rode the -drawRect method. If this is you first project then you'll need some background info so check the docs for NSView but I agree with avuthless in that you should make it easier on yourself to begin with: try getting the template progress indicator in Xcode working to give yourself insight into how a UI element connects to code.

Answer (score 1):

from my opinion thats quite a task for a beginner to handle.

I would try to deal with this issue like this:
Using core graphics to draw myself three circles: inner for data, outer for background and one in between for the loader itself. Then i would modify the loader circle to display the progress.

This should help you a lot: http://www.raywenderlich.com/33193/core-graphics-tutorial-arcs-and-paths

I would rather though use the docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH211-SW1